# Hadoop: MR launches less mappers than specified

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have Hadoop 1.2.1 installed on a remote machine (quad-core with hyper-threading), and am testing the performance of MR with 1GB of file (one file, not compressed)

When I set the split size to about 250MB so that I have four mappers. In the output file (_logs/history/job....), I see that it says `TOTAL MAP TASKS = 4`

However, when I set the split size to 1GB/8 so that it uses 8 cores, I see that the log says `TOTAL MAP TASKS = 7`. And when the split size is 1GB/16 to see what happens, the log says `TOTAL MAP TASKS = 14`. Is this because one core is designated for the jobtracker and cannot be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, most of the parameters that might affect the number of map tasks are closer to "suggestions" than hard and fast rules. It is up to the InputFormat to decide how closely it follows those parameters. For example, FileInputFormat does the following:

It computes a splitSize based on: `Math.max(minSize, Math.min(maxSize, blockSize))`. For each file, it computes how many splits of that size will cover it. For example, if the split size is 1 GB, and you have two files of sizes 1.5 GB and 2.5 GB, you will get 2 + 3 = 5 splits. However, it sometimes stretches these splits by up to 10% when getting toward the end of a file. For instance, a 1 GB split size on a 5.1 GB file will use 5 splits. There are a few more considerations too, based on specific subclass implementations.

My point is, there's some fudging going on, but it's usually reasonable behavior. You should think of the parameters that you're setting as guidelines, and trust that the InputFormat you're using is doing something reasonable when it determines how many mappers to run.

And no, it has nothing to do with the number of cores or number of task slots. That might affect how many mappers can be running concurrently, but not the total number of map tasks.

Comment: Thank you. So, mappers can be running concurrently,then what exactly "map tasks" do? If the split size is 1GB and I have an 1GB file, I'll have one map task. So, if the no. of mappers is set to 4, there should be 4 mappers running concurrently, hopefully utilizing 4 cores, right? Then, if the split size is 500MB and get 2 map tasks, task1 runs 2 mappers and task2 runs the rest of 2 mappers at the same time? And then if the split size is 100MB and get 10 map tasks, then 6 tasks could be wasted?

Comment: @kabichan yet again, not 4, but up to 4. if there is one task, one mapper will be launched. consider mappers as slots. one task occupies one slot, and not all slots might be utilized. amount of slots is bounded for a node.

Comment: I think what you're calling "mappers" is what I'm calling "map tasks". One split is handled by exactly one map task. If you have, for example, 100 splits, that means there will be 100 map tasks. And if you have four map slots, then four will be run at a time. If you have only one split, then you will only have one task, and it will not be split at all, regardless of how many slots you have. This is why it is important to have significantly more tasks than slots.